# GitHub command line instruction confusion for merging two branches with conflicts

Tags: git, github

I wanted to merge my sprint branch 2.6.7 into master today. I created a Pull Request and GitHub correctly pointed "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved" and provided following instructions:

[image]

I followed step 1, which basically says, checkout 2.6.7 branch and then pull in changes from master (reverse pull to check compatibility I guess).

As I merged master into 2.6.7 branch I had to resolve conflicts manually which I did for all conflicted files. Now `git status` does not list any conflict. Seems all happy.

At this point I am supposed to start with Step 2 which says `git checkout master`. When I execute that command it complains about local changes.

What happens to the changes I did locally on 2.6.7 branch. I can not checkout until I commit or stash my changes. I am confused with:

Do I really need to commit into 2.6.7 branch? What purpose does it solve?

Or Do I need to undo all local changes?

Please help me understand what am I missing.

Comment: "When I execute that command it complains about local changes." Have you tried to resolve those local changes?

Comment: resolve? commit or undo? please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: can you resolve those conflicts manually? If you `diffTool` what do you see?

Comment: I did. I do not see any more conflict it just that on checkout it will complain as I have local changes.

Comment: How about just stashing the local changes, create a new remote branch, push them there and start a new PR?

Comment: Yeah that could be an option. Not very efficient though. I am wondering if there are additional steps required, why would GitHub command line not include it. And if I want to do it from start what should be the actual steps that I should have followed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you push up your merge conflict changes to your local branch? When you have done so and everything is in order it should give you the option to merge pull requests via the button in your attached screenshot.

Comment: I did not wanted to update the 2.6.7 branch actually. Do I have to push these temporary changes into 2.6.7 branch?

Comment: You will need to push the merge conflict changes though? This will bring things up to date with master so that when you do want to merge the 2.6.7 branch in to master then you can. Either that or reset your 2.6.7 branch to your last commit and then checkout to a new branch from where you so desire. This would be most appropriate if you do not want to be working on your 2.6.7 branch for now.

Comment: Thanks Lilp. It will be pain in the ass to loose changes already merged. And I do want 2.6.7 intact for future usage i.e. hotfix. Any suggestion for shortcut?

Comment: what is worrying you about pushing up the changes you have made to your local 2.6.7 branch?

Comment: If it were me i would push up the merge conflicts resolutions and then i would have the choice if i wanted to merge the Pull request into master or leave it as it is and continue working on the different branches or i would stash the merge conflict changes which do not matter greatly for the time being if you don't want to merge the branch into your master branch

Comment: Sprint branch 2.6.7 is to be kept intact. I think I should have created a branch out of 2.6.7 say 2.6.7_merge and use it for this merging activity.

Comment: I found it even easier to merge master directly from 2.6.7 on my colleague machine.